# Peer can't load ledger on init, due couchdb document too large

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

On a peer init ( that was working before) I get this error:

```
2022-03-28 11:30:22.423 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 015 Deployed system chaincodes
2022-03-28 11:30:22.423 UTC [peer] Initialize -> INFO 016 Loading chain mychannel
2022-03-28 11:30:22.423 UTC [ledgermgmt] OpenLedger -> INFO 017 Opening ledger with id = mychannel
2022-03-28 11:30:22.561 UTC [kvledger] recommitLostBlocks -> INFO 018 Recommitting lost blocks - firstBlockNum=151932, lastBlockNum=151932, recoverables=[]kvledger.recoverable{(*txmgr.LockBasedTxMgr)(0xc0007ac280), (*history.DB)(0xc0007019e0)}
2022-03-28 11:30:24.191 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 019 CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f504846af00263781f48445288001003000000000000000001673753
2022-03-28 11:30:24.201 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01a CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f532d450700269506cf8445288001003000000000000000001674145
2022-03-28 11:30:24.213 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01b CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f4e3bfafd00269df9368445288001003000000000000000001673586
2022-03-28 11:30:24.218 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01c CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f4a4b49c90026d42acd8445288001003000000000000000001673194
2022-03-28 11:30:24.224 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01d CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f528876a0002650ab448445288001003000000000000000001673975
2022-03-28 11:30:24.230 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01e CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f54c1c7d3002637c8f68445288001003000000000000000001674174
2022-03-28 11:30:24.239 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 01f CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f4c8876a0002650ab1c8445288001003000000000000000001673464
2022-03-28 11:30:24.255 UTC [statecouchdb] commitUpdates -> WARN 020 CouchDB batch document delete encountered an problem. Retrying delete for document ID:balance621e8f4c4b49c90026d42ad18445288001003000000000000000001673419
2022-03-28 11:30:24.741 UTC [peer] Initialize -> ERRO 021 Failed to load ledger mychannel (error handling CouchDB request. Error:document_too_large,  Status Code:413,  Reason:lot621f3016cec5a038d5b7cdf7
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/statedb/statecouchdb.(*couchInstance).handleRequest
```

And there is no way for any peer to join again to that channel.

Versions are:

couchdb:3.1.1

Fabric peer and orderers: 2.2

Legder capabilities: Channel 1.3 , Orderer 1.1 Aplication 1.3

I have tried to restart the peer, and even to delete the document that gives error in all the couchdb, but when restarting the peer again it continues giving the same error.

Comment: Please provide more detail, such as platform fabric version, couchdb version, what investigation have you done ? eg debug logs for peer and couchdb, what actions have to tried to address the problem eg couchdb configuration, joining a new peer to the channel etc ?

Comment: More detail added. Thankyou David.

Comment: My first thought is that this is an issue with your couchdb setup. You may need to look at the couchdb logs and see about altering the couchdb configuration to accommodate ? It looks like fabric gets an error back from couch `Error:document_too_large` so maybe there is something that could be tuned in couchdb here ?

Comment: Heh. Attempt to upload a large file to ledger CouchDB seems to have killed my channel... Now for my transactions I always get these errors: channel 'xxx' not found

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the problem on the peer by increasing CouchDB max_document_size and then restarting peer. Upon restart the block's state database updates will be re-attempted and will succeed given the higher max_document_size.

Unfortunately the default for max_document_size changed from 4GB to 8MB in CouchDB 3.0. This was mentioned in the Fabric release notes when CouchDB 3.0 support was added, and is also getting added to the [Fabric CouchDB documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/couchdb_as_state_database.html#couchdb-configuration).